# How to use $map over an array of objects in an aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following example collection:

```
{ _id: 1, name: 'One', attribute_bag: { lights: { type: 'basic', value: '8' }, doors: { type: 'basic', value: '7' } } }
{ _id: 2, name: 'Two', attribute_bag: { switches: { type: 'basic', value: '2' } } }
{ _id: 3, name: 'Three', attribute_bag: { windows: { type: 'basic', value: '8' }, color: { type: 'descriptive', value: 'blue' } } }
```

I've been trying to end up with the following:

```
{ _id: 1, name: 'One', lights: '8', doors: '7' }
{ _id: 2, name: 'Two', switches: '2' }
{ _id: 3, name: 'Three', windows: '8', color: 'blue' }
```

Using the aggregation framework I've tried:

```
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: {$objectToArray: "$attribute_bag"},
              as: "attribute",
              in: ["$attribute.k", "$attribute.v.value"], 
    // alternatively {k: $attribute.k, v: $attribute.v}
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

And using $addFields + $unwind + $group. In both cases, I'm unable to pull off the combination of adding dynamic keys to the root document and pulling the 'value' field out of the embedded documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double dollar sign to refer to a variable, working example:

```
{
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
                { _id: "$_id", name: "$name" },
                {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $map: {
                            input: { $objectToArray: "$attribute_bag" },
                            in: [ "$$this.k", "$$this.v.value" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ftx-yXkWYn)